# Playing mp4 video file in Android

Tags: android, media, mp4

I am trying to play a mp4 video file from remote url in android media player.but I am getting an error code --

Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNoResources
error (1, -15)

I have searched for the error code and found that this error is returned if the resource required in processing of a request is not being available.
A typical example is, a socket node connection not available for streaming.

[link text](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/cupcake/external/opencore/doc/pvmf_return_codes.pdf)

any help would be appreciated...

Comment: With no code and no URL, it is rather difficult to help you.

Comment: how you solve this ?? I am facing same issue. can you plz share some code for playing video(.mp4) from url ?

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem by getting resumable video from Internet